# Am getting message from salesforce though am not an admin

Tags: email

You are receiving this communication because you are the admin of a Salesforce org that is generating TLS 1.0 connections. Take action before July 22, 2017 to ensure your Salesforce service continues to function normally.

However i am not an admin of this org.I am just a user.

Comment: Below the email, there would be an Org ID, can you see if its yours?
There can be other orgs where you are an admin

Comment: I can see  the messahe "You are receiving this email because our records indicate you are an administrator of Salesforce CRM Org ID".But no org ID is there.

Comment: I think Sales force have confirmed on their boards that this was sent out on mistake.

Comment: Thanks Girbot,do you have that link?

Comment: I have this problem too, how to disable the non-admin user receive this kind email alert??

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce requires you to upgrade to TLS1.1 and higher.

Below salesforce documentation has details on regarding the TLS update that salesforce is planning to upgrade to:

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000221207&type=1

I cannot really copy any sections from this document as relevant answer since the admin on your team needs to go through this document and do impact analysis and complete the necessary action to upgrade your instance to latest TLS.

Comment: Yes,I know that.My org admin received this message from salesforce. However am not an admin,just a user.Still i received this message from salesforce.That is my concern.